# How does Gnome (or LXDE or UNITY) logout?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, desktop-environment, openbox

I want to make a desktop environment and I want to make a button that logs you out back to the default GUI login. Any ideas thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Different processes usually communicate via special IPC, and most desktop environments use D-Bus as a backbone of this communication. Therefore special commands are required to send these signals (e.g. to send the log out command).

For gnome you can find the required terminal commands here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal

This command could then be put in custom desktop-launcher, for more information on that see
https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

All of this depends on the desktop environment used.